# Vector Integration - Intuition

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, intuition

I understand that an integral of a scalar valued function can be visualized as "signed area under the curve". But what about integration of a vector valued function by its parameter? Is there a visually intuitive geometric explanation for what $\int_a^b \mathbf{r}(t)\, \mathrm{d}t$ represents if $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is a function from, say, $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: If $ r $ is velocity of a particle, then $ r (t) dt $ is a tiny displacement, and the integral adds up all those tiny displacements (to get the total change in position).  In this case the letter $ v $ would have been better.

Comment: @littleO: I understand that - any geometric visualizations? (Probably should've been more clear, my bad!)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to think of $\int r(t) dt$ as the "antideriviative", so $r(t)$ is the vector rate of change of $\int r(t) dt$.  In space, $r(t)$ would be the "velocity" of $\int r(t) dt$, or its directed rate of change.

[image]

In this illustration, we approximate the antiderivative curve $\int r(t)dt$ by breaking the interval $[a,b]$ into time slices and geometrically adding $r(t)$ to determine the trajectory. We then get the definite integral by taking the total vector displacement from $t=a$ to $t=b$.

Comment: You might want to mention that the approximation gets better as the "time slices" $\Delta t_i$ get smaller and thus the weighted vectors $\mathbf r(t_i)\Delta t_i$ get smaller (but more numerous) as that's the main concept behind the integration.  Otherwise I think this is an excellent answer. +1

Comment: Where are those vectors originating from on the left hand side? are they just the result of $r(t)$ for some values of $a<t<b$? why are you adding them on the right hand side?. I feel there's a huge intuition breakthrough in this post that I'm missing.